# Embedded symbols in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am new to querying MongoDB but am running into difficulty filtering Objects where certain symbols exist. For example:

I have a number Objects in my collection `engine` that are structured like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c3a5efa6b0526729490cb2f"),
    "imsi" : "12345",
    "class_name" : "foo",
    "decoded_payload" : {
        "timestamp" : 1547329260,
        "lock_status" : "LOCKED"
    },
    "direction" : "in",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-01-12T21:41:14.998Z")
}
```

My objective is to get Objects whose `imsi` is 12345 that contain a `decoded_payload` that contains `lock_status` (lock status is of type **symbol**, not string).  Many objects do not contain these keys so I want to filter out the ones that do.

The query runs, but returns zero results (although there are many Objects that should be returned).  I am wondering if there is a syntax error that is overlooked because `lock_status` is of type symbol.  What could be the error here?

My query:

```
db.getCollection('engine').find({

$and: [

    {"decoded_payload":{
    $exists: true,
    $elemMatch: {"lock_status":{$exists:true} } 
        }
    },

    {"imsi": "12345"}


    ]})
.sort({"decoded_payload.timestamp":-1})
```

Comment: You don't need `$and` here, it's implicit. Can be simplified to `find({"decoded_payload.lock_status": {$exists: true}, "imsi": "12345"})`. Try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.getCollection('engine')
.find({"imsi": "12345", "decoded_payload": {$exists: true}, "decoded_payload.lock_status":{$exists:true}})
.sort({"decoded_payload.timestamp":-1})
```